# Reference Windows Users/username folder

Tags: windows, vbscript

I need to copy a Personal Excel Workbook file from a networked drive to the C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART on about 20 different PCs. I'd like to streamline this because it's likely to become a more common task.

Here's my current code that works if I actually have the username hardcoded in the `DestinationFile` declaration.

```
Const DestinationFile = "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\Personal.xlam"
Const SourceFile = "H:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Personal.xlam"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
    'Check to see if the file is read-only
    If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then 
        'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "H:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\", True
    Else 
        'The file exists and is read-only.
        'Remove the read-only attribute
        fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
        'Replace the file
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "H:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\", True
        'Reapply the read-only attribute
        fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
    End If
Else
    'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
    fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "H:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\", True
End If
Set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to determine the AppData folder, which looks to be your main issue:

```
Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
```